# TimeOut on StreamSource with XMLSchema

Tags: jakarta-ee, xsd

I have some problem with a bit of my code that was working perfectly fine. And now that I need to do an update of it, I have some time out error I think but only on the production server, it's perfectly fine on the developpement one.

The time out is always 25 five seconds, but the code excecute just fine after it... it's nevertheless blocking our production server.

```
// 1. Lookup a factory for the W3C XML Schema language
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    Source xsdSource = new StreamSource(XSD_FILE);          

    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(xsdSource);
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlContent.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    Source sourceContent = new StreamSource(is);
    validator.validate(sourceContent);
```

After putting log everywhere it is this line that takes 25 seconds. It is reading 9 xsd files on the same server

```
Source xsdSource = new StreamSource(XSD_FILE);
```

If you have any idea on what could be causing that...

Thank you very much

Leena

Answer (score 0):

If `XSD_FILE` is including/importing other XSDs (which in turn are including/importing other XSDs, and so on), then here are some possibilities to check:

- The aggregate time to read all of the XSDs is too long.
- One of the included/imported XSDs is being served from a host that's unresponsive or inaccessible to the production server.